# How to change Key of a JsonArray using streams in Java?

Tags: json, java-8, stream

I have a JsonArray of JsonObjects. What I'm looking for is to how do I modify the value of the keys in the JsonObjects using Streams.
Eg. `JsonArray a = [{"company_id":45, "name":"XYZ"},{"company_id":35, "name":"AAZ"}]` to
`a= [{"id":45, "name":"XYZ"},{"id":35, "name":"AAZ"}]` . I couldn't find any method which could replace the key, so came over here.
What I'm doing right now is something like this:
`a = a.stream().map(JsonObject.class::cast).forEach(element -> element.get??? });`

Comment: when you say modify, is it only converting from comapny_id to id or something else?

Comment: @pvpkiran yes only converting from comapny_id to id.

Comment: JsonArray is of type what? which library?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `a.put("id", a.remove("company_id"));`

Comment: Should be a comment